# Text overflow options for Combobox in using a Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, text, combobox, overflow

I have a combo box (dropdown) in a Windows forms. I'm searching for a way to show any text that exceeds the length of the Combobox to show the remaining text as an ellipsis or "..."

I'm familiar with how this is done in other UI tools like WPF but I'm wondering if this even possible in Winforms. I couldn't find a property or any other option.

Thanks,

Comment: You can probably do that with an [owner-drawn combobox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawitem?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: If you use `e.Graphics.DrawString`: with [StringFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformat) setting [`Trimming`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.stringformat.trimming) `= StringTrimming.EllipsisCharacter;`. If you use `TextRenderer.DrawText`, you can set its `TextFormatFlags` to `TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis`. Set `ComboBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;` It applies to the Items shown in the DropDown.